# vb6 & character after a variable

Tags: vb6

There is the following in some code I'm trying to figure out:

```
For I& = 1 To...
```

I'm not familiar with the & after a variable.  What does that represent?

After some further [research](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-273013.html), it looks like the I& is being defined as a type LONG.  Now my questions is why would they be doing this?  Is it overkill or just legacy code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right - putting an *ampersand* & after a number or a variable means that it is of a Long 32-bits type.

So the answer is, how many iterations does the loop need - is it possible, that it would exceed 16 bits integer?

> With no data type identifier after the i, it is implied to be of the native Integer (the default). Therefore this i is expressed as an Integer, which makes it a 16-bit i.

So, I'd say it is the original developer had this habit of explicitly stating the variable type with &, and whether it was really needed there depends on the number of iterations that the For..Next loop has to support in this case.

Answer (score 13):

The legacy BASIC Language had several ways of declaring variables. You could use data type suffixes ($, %, &, !, or #) to the variable name

```
x$ = "This is a string"   ' $ defines a string
y% = 10                   ' % defines an integer
y& = 150                  ' & defines a long integer
y! = 3.14                 ' ! defines a single
y# = 12.24                ' # defines a double
```

Comment: y^ -- defines LongPtr

Comment: @drgs LongPtr does not exist in VB6.

Answer (score 5):

Legacy.  Old-school (pre-.NET) Visual Basic used variable name suffixes in lieu of (optionally) variable types.

Comment: Wow - a downvote for a question about a language I've coded in since 1995.

Comment: +1. I started coding in the language in 1988 (I assume we're counting earlier versions here since VB6 wasn't released until 1998)

Comment: @MarkJ: *Visual* Basic first came out in 1991. I jumped in at the VB3 level, after using Turbo Basic for a few years. TB had the worst variable naming convention I've ever seen: variable names could be any length, but the compiler only took note of the first two letters, so the variables `BOY` and `BODY` were actually the same variable.

Comment: The suffix-symbol declaration was just a backward-compatibility feature in VB6.  Its use had been deprecated for some time.

Comment: @Bob: its use had been deprecated by *me* since the first time I encountered it. In my opinion, it was the kind of shorthand nonsense preferred by programmers who don't know how to type.

Comment: These suffixes can be useful in the immediate pane.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is either old code ported forward to VB6 from QBasic, etc. or else just a bad habit some individual programmer had from that era.  While kind of sloppy its meaning should be obvious to a VB6 programmer, since it can be used with numeric literals in many cases too:

```
MsgBox &HFFFF
MsgBox &HFFFF&
```

These display different values because they *are* different values.

Yes it means Long but it often reflects somebody who fails to set the IDE option to auto-include Option Explicit in new modules when created.

Comment: Why do I suspect you as the downvoter?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using symbolic notation  (Integer - %, Long - &, Single - !, Double - #, String - $) is an excellent method for variable declaration and usage.  It’s usage is consistent with "structured programming" and it’s a good alternative to Hungarian notation.

With Hungarian notation, one might define a string filename as “strFileName”, where the variable name is preceded by a lower case abbreviation of the variable type.  The is contrary to another good programming practice of making all global variables begin with an upper case first letter and all local variables begin with a lower case.   This helps the reader of your code instantly know the scope of a variable.   Ie.   firstName$  is a local string variable;   LastName$  is a global string variable.

As with all programming, it’s good to follow conventions, ..whether you define your own conventions or somebody else’s conventions or industry conventions.    Following no conventions is a very poor programming practice.   Using symbolic notation is one type of naming convention.

Comment: I'm sorry but the symbols are not a naming convention, and [systems Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) doesn't actually define the data type (outside of `Def*` and the first character).

Comment: Actually symbolic notation "is" a naming convention as well as a means of defining a data type in vb.  Hungarian notation does not define a data type.  It too is just a naming convention.

Comment: I agree with @Deanna.  If it's enforced by the compiler (or interpreter), it is not a naming convention.  A naming convention is something optional that a programmer adopts and can change.  You can abuse a naming convention by, for example, declaring `Dim strFirstName As Long`, but you cannot abuse a type declaration character by declaring `Dim firstName$ As Long`.

Comment: Symbolic notation is not enforced by the compiler, therefore it is a naming convention.   Symbolic notation is a choice.

Comment: The Dim firstName$ as Long is an invalid statement and VB does not allow such syntax.     One would either declare a variable as Dim firstName$ or Dim firstName as string.   But you cannot use both in the declaration.   The $ sign indicates that the variable is a string.   The use of the $ sign is optional throughout the program regardless of the syntax used.